# Appstore app version number

Tags: iphone, app-store, version, itunes

I have updated an app in the Appstore. Its new bundle version is 1.15 (in binary details) and its version is 1.2 (in app details). The previous version was 1.1 and 1.1. After updating it, the users who had installed the previous version don´t receive a notification of the new version. May this problem be related to the bundle version? I mean, 1.1x is a newer version for Appstore than 1.2, or should I have set 1.2 in the binary details?

Comment: what version no. did you set in info.plist?

Comment: i think that might be the problem,bcoz as programming point of view email notification programming didn't notice the change in version no. it might have check 1.2 didnt find it, hence no email notification were sended

Comment: As usual way or upgrading version are like this 1.0,1.1,1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers between dots are considered as whole, non-decimal numbers.

This means that version 1.2 is an older release than 1.15 as the ".15" is considered to be 15 and the ".2" is considered to be 2

The new bundle version should have been 1.1.1

Comment: Friends of mine (also developers) have said to me the same: they have uploaded apps with similar version numbers that mine. However, there was no error in those cases. I have phoned to AppStore, and they have said to me that they are to revise my case.

Answer (score 0):

In the iTunesConnect I have found this advice:

The version number of the app you are adding. Numbering should follow typical software versioning conventions (for example, 1.0 or 1.0.1 or 1.1).